# connecting speaker and mic to GSM SIM 900

Tags: microphone, gsm, sim900

I have a gsm module but unfortunately it doesnt have an output for mic and speakers. I need to integrate mic and speaker too. In my GSM module, there are male pins available for `mic_P` `mic_N` for microphone and `spk_P` `spk_N` but I dont know how to connect these to speakers and microphone. Does anyone have any idea about this?
Please share.

I am attaching a pic of my gsm module: [image]

Comment: Quite often you can just connect MIC_P to the positive side of an electret microphone and MIC_N to the negative. Likewise with a small speaker or set of headphones. The module won't drive a large speaker. Check if there is a voltage across MIC_P and MIC_N.

Comment: @pjc50 electret microphone... is it the normal microphone or something else?

Comment: It's .. an electret microphone. It should be in the description in a parts catalog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [**electret**](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/8635) microphone. Connect its positive to `MICP` & negative to `MIC_N`.

For speakers, I have used [this](http://k1.arduino.vn/img/2014/05/27/0/510_1231-1401207271-0-lxf104.tut-arduino.speaker.jpg) type of speakers. Connections are same.

Alternatively, for testing purpose you can also use your headphone. Cut the headphone wire and you will find wires to connect with **`SPK_P`** **`SPK_N`** **`MIC_p`** **`MIC_N`** .